# what is this part called in iPhone screen? want to use it to decide wether screen is home screen

Tags: ios, testing, automated-tests, auto

all.
I am new in ios auto testing. 
what is the red circled part called in iPhone screen? I want to use it to decide wether screen is home screen. 
anyone who has experience in this can also give some advice, is this method a good way to decide home screen?
thanks a lot!
[image: Reference image here]

Comment: it's called pagecontrol

Answer (score 1):

That is a `UIPageControl`. But I'm afraid it won't help you to decide if you're in the home screen, tests run in full screen and when the apps are in background they don't (usually) have access to what is displayed on screen, as that would be a huge security hole.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I'm using webdriveragent. I want to find another way to decide home screen page because the decision method that WDA use can not work in ios 11.2.   `- (BOOL)fb_isApplicationBoardVisible
{
  [self resolve];
  // the dock (and other icons) don't seem to be consistently reported as
  // visible. esp on iOS 11 but also on 10.3.3
  return self.otherElements[@"Dock"].isEnabled;
}`

Comment: In that case, I suggest you open an issue with [them](https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/issues). You're likely not the only user to experience this problem, so they'll be the first to find out a solution.

Even if you could detect the page control, it is not indicative of being in the home screen, as that is a standard control that any app can use. Maybe it would work for the app you're testing if it doesn't use that control in particular, but not as a general solution.

Comment: @zhaoxuepingswag I think no other answers will come forth, care to mark mine as the accepted answer? thanks